# How can I generate the template like table?

Tags: templates, report

I need to write in the following template :

[image]

Could you tell me how I can generate in the latex?

Comment: First, it is usually better to include in your question some code of what you have tried thus far.  It can be very hard to guess what the overall goal is without some context. As for the specific problem, it is probably better to not think of this as a table, but as a series of framed boxes, where one of them contains a series of enumerated lists.  For this, you could look at [tcolorbox](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox) or [mdframed](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mdframed), and [enumitem](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) for the lists.

Comment: Do you want to create this table, or do you want to comply with the instructions in the table?

Answer (score 3):

A solution with `tcolorbox`:

[image: MWE]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem} 
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable}
\tcbset{breakable}
\begin{document}
\sffamily
\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=gray!40!,boxsep=1mm,arc=0mm,boxrule=1pt]
\bfseries SECTION B: Written report\par\medskip
I hate \MakeUppercase{CAPITALIZE} or \uline{underline}, but the  worse  ishave \underline{\MakeUppercase{both}} together. But this is only for demostration purposes. Bla bla bla \ldots
\end{tcolorbox}
\vspace{-8pt}
\begin{tcolorbox}[,colback=gray!20!, boxsep=1mm,arc=0mm,boxrule=1pt]
\uline{\textbf{Guidelines for Report Writting}}\par
\begin{enumerate}[(a)]
    \item \lipsum[2] % bla bla bla  
\end{enumerate}
\end{tcolorbox}\vspace{-8pt}
\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=white,boxsep=1em,arc=0mm,boxrule=1pt]
\section{Introduction} \rmfamily
\lipsum[3-8] % long bla bla bla
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```